# Google VRView for Web - Detect when a 360° video finishes

Tags: video, html5-video, google-vr, webvr, 360-degrees

My requirement is really simple: I need to load another 360° video with Google VRView for Web as soon as the current running video has ended.

There are 4 types of events described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web#vrview_events) but unfortunately no event to detect when the video finishes. I couldn't even find a property to disable the loop.

Has anybody been able to implement something like this?

```js
var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
    video: 'link/to/first-video.mp4',
    is_stereo: true
  });


// I couldn't find an event like this or another solution

vrView.on('end', function() {

  vrView.setContent({
    video: 'link/to/second-video.mp4',
    is_stereo: true
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation shows 4 types of events, as you say, the source on GitHub seems to actually support and additional one for 'ended' (https://github.com/googlevr/vrview).

You can see it defined in main.js and used in player.js:

```js
Player.prototype.onMessage_ = function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  if (!message || !message.type) {
    console.warn('Received message with no type.');
    return;
  }
  var type = message.type.toLowerCase();
  var data = message.data;

  switch (type) {
    case 'ready':
    case 'modechange':
    case 'error':
    case 'click':
    case 'ended':
      if (type === 'ready') {
        if (data !== undefined) {
          this.duration = data.duration;
    }
      }
```